Are there any (anglophone) countries besides the US that declare grenades to be "weapons of mass destruction"?
18 USC § 2332a(c)(2) defines a "weapon of mass destruction" to be "any destructive device as defined in section 921 of this title" (besides some things more widely considered as such in vernacular, like chemical or nuclear weapons). And that 921 section defines a "destructive device" to be any explosive bomb, grenade, etc. So, a [regular army] grenade is a "weapon of mass destruction" for the purposes of US criminal law (at least in some sections thereof).
Are there any other countries (primarily anglophone since translation might be an issue) having laws that define a grenade to be a "weapon of mass destruction"?

Tagged with terrorism because I think the def is for the purpose of such offenses, although 2332a doesn't use the T-word as such, it's about attacks. (The later 2332i is specifically about "nuclear terrorism".)

Almost every country prohibits private ownership of grenades. The terminology varies widely and isn't consistent even within U.S. law. The definition of the term "weapons of mass destruction" in 18 U.S.C. § 2332a(c)(2) is not the same as the definition of the same term in U.S. authorization of use of military force laws or in certain treaties to which the U.S. is a party. In common law legal system, words do not have a single consistent meaning and must always be understood in the specific context where they arise. The question suggests a lack of awareness of this feature of legal terminology.

@ohwilleke: I'm pretty sure it's prohibited in most countries. I was curious about terminology.

germany
There is a legal definition of Kriegswaffen (weapons of war), which are regulated separately from regular weapons. This term includes hand grenades and even armor-piercing rifle ammunition, but also attack helicopters and nuclear weapons. Illegal possession is punished harder than the illegal possession of ordinary firearms, and permits are almost impossible to get.
